# how to obtain picture in camera with MediaStore

Tags: android, mediastore

I try to use MediaStore to get picutures that stored `in SDcard:DCIM/Camera`.my code is like this:

```
Cursor track = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
null);
```

but I get all pictures that in SDcards,I need get only in `DCIM/Camera`,help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code.

```
String SD_CARD_CAM_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "DCIM" + File.separator + "Camera";
File file =new File(SD_CARD_CAM_DIR);
Cursor track = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Uri.fromFile(file), null, null,null,null);
```